# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fadeToggle' of null

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I wrote this little Javascript to hide **.price-box**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
var visible = window.localStorage.getItem("visiblestate");
if (visible != null){
    var el = $('.price-box');
    if (visible == "true"){
        el.show();
    }else{
        el.hide();
    }
}
});
function ToggleState(){
var el = $('.price-box');
el.fadeToggle(500,"swing",function(){
    window.localStorage.setItem("visiblestate",el.is(":visible"));  
});
}
```

I put this button in: toolbar.phtml:

```
input type="button" value="Toggle" onClick="ToggleState()"
```

And I use this CSS:

```
.hide {visibility:hidden}
```

I tested it with everything in one HTML and it is working. But when I use it together with Magento by adding:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/toggleprice.js</name></action>
```

to **local.xml**

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fadeToggle' of null

Could anybody please tell me why it is working when I test it but not if I use it in Magento?

Thank you very much

Edit: This is my complete test-page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.hide {visibility:hidden;}
</style>

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
var visible = window.localStorage.getItem("visiblestate");
if (visible != null){
    var el = $('.price-box');
    if (visible == "true"){
        el.show();
    }else{
        el.hide();
    }
}
});
function ToggleState(){
var el = $('.price-box');
el.fadeToggle(500,"swing",function(){
    window.localStorage.setItem("visiblestate",el.is(":visible"));  
});
}
</script>
<body>
<p><div class="price-box" style="background-
color:#FC0;width:100px;height:100px"></div></p>
<p><div class="price-box" style="background-
color:#FC0;width:100px;height:100px"></div></p>
<p>
<input type="button" value="Toggle" onClick="ToggleState()" />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the `.price-box` element definitely on the page you're testing?

Comment: Yes, the <div class="price-box> is on my test-page where the code is working. I put my test-page into my first post.

Comment: I meant on the Magento page you were testing sorry.

Comment: Yes, it is on the catalog/product/price.phtml:

<div class="price-box">

Comment: Note: The `html` element always has *exactly* two child elements: `head` and `body`. When the parser encounters the `<style>` tag after the `head` has been closed, it automatically opens the `body` element and places the `style` and `script` elements inside it. The extraneous `<body>` tag that occurs later will probably be ignored.